# Html javascript image onload not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to load an image into a canvas context but the function onload from the Image object does not fire:

```
var img_url = document.getElementById('img').src.split('?')[0]
console.log('img: '+img_url.substring(8))

canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");

LoadImageToCtx1();

function LoadImageToCtx1()
{
    var base_image = new Image();
    //base_image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

    var path = serverip+'load?path=/'+img_url.substring(8)+"&"+(new Date().getTime())
    console.log("LoadImageToCtx: "+path)
    base_image.onload = function(){
        console.log('load img!')
        ctx1.drawImage(base_image,0,0);
    }
    base_image.src = path;//-->file// cut
}
```

I did tried already the trick of the random number into the path, the src declatation is after the onload function but still the onload is not fired... any idea?

Comment: Is the image even loading? Ie, is the url you are using giving a 404

Comment: You are setting the src of the `base_img` to an IP address directly followed by a path without a slash separating it and without any protocol (http:// or https://) in front - that will definitely not work. So first you should get your image URL in `path` right. Also, your `serverip` is not even defined.

Comment: @Connum yeah I forgot to put http:// in front. Thanks!